# How to store objects from different classes in one array and call the same function (which definitions are different) in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, oop, interface, subclass, superclass

I have two subclasses:

- Line
- Arc

Their objects will be creating a path by appending them on their end. These have their own "plotCurve" methods. I want to store these objects in an array in order such as:

```
path = [line1,line2,arc1,line3,arc2,arc3,line4,arc4,arc5...];
```

(I think "path" should be the object of superclass "Path")
when I code something like;

```
for i=1:size(path)
    path(i).plotCurve;
    hold on
end
```

the result should be shown. I should be able to see the whole path. (So, when the object of "Line" comes "plotCurve" method should be run and same for Arc objects).

Comment: What data type/variable type are we expecting line and arc to be?

Comment: those are classes, there are 10-15 float properties for each.

Comment: No need for inheritance in this case. Make `path` a cell array, you can populate that with objects of the two classes (or anything else). Then you can call the `plotCurve` method of each object, as long as the object defines such a method, it will work.

Comment: @CrisLuengo yes you are right. Thats actually how I already did. However, I would like to know how to do it without using cell arrays using oop.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like subclassing from [`matlab.mixin.Heterogeneous`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.mixin.heterogeneous-class.html) allows this behaviour:

```matlab
classdef Path < matlab.mixin.Heterogeneous
%...
end

classdef Line < Path
%...
end

classdef Arc < Path
%...
end

path = [Line,Line,Arc,Line,Arc,Arc];

figure, hold on
for i=1:numel(path)
    path(i).plotCurve;
end
```

I found this here: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/4354-matlab-handle-class-violates-polymorphism-on-handle-equivalence

Though I think it's easier to make `path` a cell array, there is no difference in behavior in the code above, except using different indexing: `path{i}.plotCurve`.

Answer (score 2):

Further to @Cris's suggestion, I would suggest a refinement a bit like this (untested)

```
classdef Path < matlab.mixin.Heterogeneous
    methods (Abstract, Access = protected)
        plotOne(obj)
    end
    methods (Sealed)
        function plotAll(objs)
            figure; hold on;
            for obj = objs(:).' % loop over all elements
                plotOne(obj);
            end
        end
    end 
end
```

This lets you call the `plotAll` method on an array of `Path` - that method must be `Sealed`. It unwraps the array to call the indivual `plotOne` methods on each element.

Comment: Hi, sorry for digging out an old post. Does this work for you? I'm getting the error message `Cannot call method 'plotOne' because 'obj' is heterogeneous and 'plotOne' is not sealed.` So it seems that also plotOne must be sealed.

Comment: You must ensure you call `plotOne` with a scalar instance...